# How to group rows after another grouping in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table called correctObjects. In this tablet here a lot of grups which has different number records. One example is given below as grup 544 has 5 rows in table.  So firstly, I should group all records by GRUP COLUMN then I must do inner matching by CAP COLUMN. So in grup#544 there is three different CAP values then I must give Inner Group number to these records. How can I do these two level grouping process. GRUP column is already done. Inner Grup Column is null in every records.
[image]

After Inner Group process, It must look like as belows:
[image]

I am using Oracle 11g R2 and PL/SQL Developer

Comment: What SQL did you use to get the first set of results? How are your rows ordered?  Maybe related to the previous question, what causes a row to be `inner_grup` 1 vs. 2 or 3?  I understand how they are grouped, but not how they are ranked.  And finally, what would be the expected result if you have multiple distinct `grup` values. You are not very clear on that.

Comment: I want only to match rows that in same grup and have same cap. So inner grup number doesn't matter.

Comment: Why do you need to group by those two fields, GRUP and CAP - is that for further processing? INNER_GRUP only gives "names" to these smaller groups within GRUP; sstan's solution gives you more, these smaller groups are also ordered by the value in CAP. If you only need the smaller groups for further processing, you don't need the INNER_GRUP column at all; you can always GROUP BY two or more columns, not just by one column. Perhaps if you state the final problem you are trying to solve, the forum can help you with that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks certain details, so I'll just give you a starting point, and you can tweak it to suit your needs.

It's not entirely clear, but the way I understand it, you want to *rank* the different rows by `cap`. And I think the ranking is independent for every distinct `grup` value.

What's not clear to me is why `125 mm` is ranked `1`, and `62 mm` is ranked `2`. Is it based on the value?  Is it based on which row is the first one, and if so, how are the rows ordered?  Or maybe you don't really care which one is first or second, as long as they are grouped correctly.  I'll have to assume the latter.

In any case, it sounds like you want to use the `dense_rank()` analytic function in some form:

```
select mip, startmi, cap, grup,
       dense_rank() over (partition by grup order by cap) as inner_grup
  from tbl
```

Comment: I want only to match rows that in same grup and have same cap. So inner grup number doesn't matter. Is your answer do this job. I don't have any experience on partition or dense_rank() in oracle. I will search these. Thank you.

Comment: I try that you said and it totally works for me. Thnanks a lot.